# Highly reliable storage for a 'log' / time series

Tags: java, persistence

In an application I'm working on, I need a write-behind data log. That is, the application accumulates data in memory, and can hold all the data in memory. It must, however, persist, tolerate reasonable faults, and allow for backup.

Obviously, I could write to a SQL database; Derby springs to mind for easy embedding. I'm not tremendously fond of the dealing with a SQL API (JDBC however lipsticked) and I don't need any queries, indices, or other decoration. The records go out, and on restart, I need to read them all back.

Are there any other suitable alternatives?

Comment: What counts as "reasonable faults"? You really need to define the circumstances you want to guard against in order to work out a solution.

Comment: Obviously not explosions next to the disk drive. Hopefully crashes of the application or the system it is running on -- or -- the same level of assurance, as, say, a copy of MySQL running on the same machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a just a simple log file.

As data comes in, store in memory and write (append) to a file.  `write()` followed by `fsync()` will guarantee (on most systems, read your system and filesystem docs carefully) that the data is written to persistent storage (disc).  These are the same mechanisms any database engine would use to get data in persistent storage.

On restart, reload the log.  Occasionally, trim the front of the log file so data usage doesn't grow infinitely.  Or, model the log file as a circular buffer the same size as what you can hold in memory.

Comment: Yes, that's the clear starting point. What if the plug gets pulled in mid-write? Can anything I grab guarantee that I don't have half-a-record sitting at the end of the last file? Or do I just have to code something to cope with that?

Comment: Or, in other words, hasn't someone else written one of these in Java and published it FOSS?

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm proposing here is library-worthy.  It's a for-loop with a write() + fsync().  Many filesystems will guarantee that write() operations are atomic (e.g. all or none) -- double check your system.  If you really want to be conservative, design your log records with a length or bounding characters so that you know they're complete, and ignore any partial trailing record.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at (now Oracle) Berkeley DB for Java? The "Direct Persistence Layer" is actually quite simple to use. Docs [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/gsg/JAVA/dpl.html) for DPL.

Has different options for backups comes with a few utilities. Runs embedded.

(Licensing: a form of the BSD License I beleive.)

Comment: The license used to be GPL unless you paid them. I'll look at it now.

Comment: BDB is a key value store. I don't want to have to have keys. I want reliable/recoverable writing of a log. DPL is even worse in this respect, as I don't want to write java objects.

Comment: ok. I was thinking about a real simple usage where the log would be a simple Date + String (or whatever type you data is) container object. Put when writing, Get when loading up. Real simple. And you get hot backup for essentially free with that. Sounds way easier than going with SQL. But I see your point. BTW, it's neither GPL nor BSD, sorry about that.